# (Linux AMI) EMR Cluster version of `free` command

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, hadoop-yarn, aws-cli

I'm trying to allocate memory to spark when I start up pyspark from an AWS Linux AMI - ie, pass precise arguments to the `driver-memory` and `executor-memory` parameters when I call pyspark.

I understand I can look here at the [Instance Types](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/) page for the off-the-shelf answer to *How much memory do I have on each of this EMR cluster's instances?* but I'd like to know if I can do this ("live") from the aws cli itself, so I can see how much I'm actually working with after my bootstrapped spin-up process.

I am also aware of the `free` command in Linux, but that appears to give me the free memory of only the master node into which I am ssh'd.  I am also aware of the YARN UI and Hadoop APIs, but in this case I'd like to check from the command line, if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information you are looking for about the cluster memory usage will be available in the yarn manager.

```
Yarn top
```

Yarn Manger Provides the information about the nodes and memory used and memory available.
Keeps the track of your all applications.

The following link provides more information about yarn 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-web-interfaces.html

[image]

Comment: Yes, valid answer.  I'm also aware that the Hadoop API itself could do this programmatically / if I didn't have access to the YARN UI.  But I'd like to see if there s a way to do this right from the command line.

Comment: Nice! Closest I've seen.  Seems to give the sum of all `VCores` and `Mem(GB)`, so it would need to be divided by the number of number of `NodeManager(s)` if I'm reading this correctly, so wont be exactly / per cluster readout.  But for now this is top response.